# Prove that the angle between two vectors is equal to the sum of its composing angles

Tags: inner-products

So far I've been stuck into this problem. It's easy to get geometrically, but I can't find a rigorous proof using only vectors and the properties of inner product and norms.

Let $v, w \in \mathbb{R^2}$. Using the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R^2}$, prove that if $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $v-w$, $\psi$ is the angle between $-w$ and $v-w$, and $\alpha$ is the angle between $v$ and $-w$, then $\alpha = \psi + \theta$ (as shown on my awful picture below).

That is, prove that

$$\arccos\left(\frac{v \cdot (-w)}{|v||-w|}\right) = \arccos\left(\frac{v \cdot (v-w)}{|v||v-w|}\right) + \arccos\left(\frac{-w \cdot (v-w)}{|-w||v-w|}\right)$$

Maybe I'm missing a property from the inverse cosine function. Any tip? Thanks.

[Geometric representation picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekyT5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

\begin{equation}
\arccos(x)+\arccos(y)=\arccos\left(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)
\end{equation}
with $x=\frac{v \cdot (v-w)}{|v||v-w|}$ and $y=\frac{-w \cdot (v-w)}{|-w||v-w|}$.

You can get that formula applying a simple law:

if we have
\begin{equation}
\cos\alpha=x\\\cos\beta=y
\end{equation}

then $\alpha+\beta=\arccos x+\arccos y=\arccos[\cos(\alpha+\beta)]$. Now:

\begin{equation}
\arccos[\cos(\alpha+\beta)]=\arccos[\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta]=\\=\arccos\left[\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sqrt{1-\cos^2\alpha}\sqrt{1-\cos^2\beta}\right]=\\=\arccos\left[\cos(\arccos x)\cos(\arccos y)-\sqrt{1-\cos^2\arccos x}\sqrt{1-\cos^2\arccos y}\right]=\\=\arccos\left(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)
\end{equation}

with $0\le\alpha,\beta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ (like in your problem).

Comment: omg, it took me so long, so many steps, but that property worked (where does it come from?), thank you so much! :-D

Comment: I added something...I hope it is useful;-)